# Hibernate IN/ANY with custom converter in Criteria

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, hibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a simple model say

```
    class A {
        @Type(type = "com.vivek.persistence.ListAsSQLArrayUserType")
        @Column(name = "string_array", columnDefinition = "text[]")
        List<String> stringArray;
    }
```

Now I want to search any item exists in the stringArray Column.
I can do this simply using sql native query :

```
select * from A WHERE 'abc' = any(string_array)
```

But I am not able to figure out any way through Hibernate Criteria API.
I have tried ***IN predicate*** but it simply do not work and return empty result.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add Java code of the criteria ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution which can be specific to postgres using ***criteriaBuilder.function()***. It resolved my issue.

```
String value = "abc"; // anything
criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.literal(value), criteriaBuilder.function("any", String.class, root.get(name)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had applied the solution below to column of ENUM type with help of @Vivek Dhiman answer. While building criteria:

Before:

```
builder.equal(from.get("columnName"), criteria.getValue());
```

After:

```
builder.equal(from.get("columnName"), HttpMethod.valueOf(criteria.getValue()));
```

Column

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "column_name")
private HttpMethod columnName;
```

Builder:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
```